# How to convert Cell Data to Point Data in .vtu file

Tags: python, numpy, vtk

I am really new to the use of .vtu files and I need to extract grid data and data from some arrays in the solution to store them in two .npy files, one for the grid and one for the variables, and then go on with some post-processing.
While I was able to extract points from the grid and cell data from the arrays and convert them in numpy arrays, I don't get how to tranform Cell data to Point data.

Here is my code:

```
reader = vtk.vtkXMLUnstructuredGridReader() 
reader.SetFileName("myfile.vtu")
reader.Update()

# Get the coordinates of nodes in the mesh
nodes_vtk_array= reader.GetOutput().GetPoints().GetData()

OH_vtk_array = reader.GetOutput().GetCellData().GetArray('OH mass frac.')

#Get the coordinates of the nodes
nodes_nummpy_array = vtk_to_numpy(nodes_vtk_array)
x,y,z= nodes_nummpy_array[:,0] , nodes_nummpy_array[:,1] , nodes_nummpy_array[:,2]


OH_numpy_array = vtk_to_numpy(OH_vtk_array)
OH = OH_numpy_array
```

I hope that someone can help me even if it is a very stupid question :)

Thanks a lot in advance!!

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [CellDataToPointData](https://vtk.org/doc/nightly/html/classvtkCellDataToPointData.html) filter. (python as same API)

Something like:

```
converter = vtk.vtkCellDataToPointData()
converter.ProcessAllArraysOn()
converter.SetInputConnection(reader.GetOutputPort())
converter.Update()
OH_vtk_array = converter.GetOutput().GetPointData().GetArray('OH mass frac.')
```

Comment: thanks a lot for the answer! I tried and unfortunately I get this:                                  'AttributeError: 'vtkFiltersCorePython.vtkCellDataToPointData' object has no attribute 'SetProcessAllArraysOn''. Maybe I am missing some import or something? @Nico Vuaille

Comment: If I comment SetProcessAllArraysOn() and I execute the program, then I get                                 
  **File "/neshvtu3.py", line 39, in <module>
    OH_numpy_array = vtk_to_numpy(OH_vtk_array) **  
  _File "/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/vtk/util/numpy_support.py", line 215, in vtk_to_numpy
    typ = vtk_array.GetDataType()  _                                                                                       AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'GetDataType'

Comment: Sorry, I made a mistake, it is `ProcessAllArraysOn ()`. I updated my answer

Comment: I still get this :( mybe it is useful to add that I am using python 2.7, maybe I have to switch to python 3. **AttributeError: 'vtkFiltersCorePython.vtkCellDataToPointData' object has no attribute 'ProcessAllArraysOn'** @NicoVuaille

Comment: Ok, I tried with Python3 and at least it takes the attributes of the function, Anyway, I am still having this problem when converting the data into a numpy array:               **Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/tont_fe/software/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/vtkmodules/util/numpy_support.py", line 216, in vtk_to_numpy
    typ = vtk_array.GetDataType()
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'GetDataType'**

Comment: Ok I think I solved the issue. The point is that instead of reader. in the OH_vtk_array assignment I have to use converter. instead, so like that:                                                        **OH_vtk_array = converter.GetOutput().GetPointData().GetArray('OH mass frac.')**

Comment: Oh well, I went to fast, sorry ... Answer Updated

Comment: Thanks a lot!!! Maybe to be also clear to the others you can add to your super useful and kind answer that we have to use the latest version of vtk package and python 3 because in python 2 is not working :) thanks a lot!!!!

Answer (score 0):

From vtkIOXMLPython.vtkXMLUnstructuredGridReader

```
reader = vtk.vtkXMLUnstructuredGridReader()  
reader.SetFileName(filenameVTU) 
reader.Update()
```

From vtkCommonCorePython.vtkPoints

```
points = reader.GetOutput().GetPoints()
coordinates = np.array(points.GetData())
```

From vtkCommonExecutionModelPython.vtkAlgorithmOutput

```
reader.GetOutputPort()
```

From vtkFiltersCorePython.vtkCellDataToPointData

```
converter = vtk.vtkCellDataToPointData()
```

Here, SetInputConnection method requires a vtkAlgorithmOutput

```
converter.SetInputConnection(reader.GetOutputPort() )
converter.Update()
```

Finally from vtkCommonCorePython.vtkDoubleArray

```
pointArray = np.array(converter.GetOutput().GetPointData().GetArray('YOUR CELL DATA ARRAY NAME'))
```

Additionally, you can assert

```
assert pointArray.shape[0] == coordinates.shape[0]
```